# Preventing use query string on $resource POST

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I have a angularJS application with an api service defined as follows:

```
(function ()
{
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .factory('api', apiService);

    /** @ngInject */
    function apiService($resource)
    {
        var api = {};

        // Base Url
        api.baseUrl = 'http://localhost:37243/';

        api.Auth = $resource(api.baseUrl + 'auth/:verb', {}, {
            login: {
                method: "POST",
                params: {
                    verb: 'credentials'
                }
            },
            logout: {
                method: "GET",
                params: { verb: 'logout' }
            },
            getSession: {
                method: "GET",
                params: { verb: 'session' }
            }
        });

        return api;
    }

})();
```

and I am executing the login method from an Auth service like this:

```
authService.login = function (user, success, error) {
        var apiAuth = new api.Auth();

            apiAuth.$login(user).then(
                function (response) {
                    var loginData = response;
                    authService.getSession();

                    $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginSuccess);
                    success(loginData);
                }, function (response) {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginFailed);
                    error(response);
                });
        };
```

The api call is working but it is passing the payload in the query string rather than a data payload.  I guess I have $resource configured incorrectly but cannot work out why.

What is being sent:

> http://localhost:37243/auth/credentials?password=Password1&username=admin

What I want to be sent:

> POST http://localhost:37243/auth/credentials
>       {password: 'Password1', username: 'admin'}

Any ideas?

Comment: try replace the verb param from the login resource

Comment: @Erez I'm not 100% sure what you mean but I've tried overriding the url to have no :verb parameter and deleted the param object from the method override without any joy...?

Comment: login: {
                method: "POST",
                params: {
                    cerd: 'credentials'
                }
            },

Comment: or try adding { verb: "@ver" }, here $resource(api.baseUrl + 'auth/:verb', {verb: "@verb"}, {

Comment: No difference; to be honest - I don't know why you're suggesting this - the call works but I want to hide the query string params; I don't see why it has anything to do with the verb?  Do you mind explaining your thinking?

Comment: this is how it works for me

Comment: you can see also this question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529483/how-do-i-not-send-url-template-parameters-with-request-body-in-angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked out the problem...

The reason is because I'm instantiating the resource object Auth and then executing the method.

From the ngResource documentation, the method signatures for "non-GET" methods (like mine) are:

> non-GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], postData,
> [success], [error])
>
> non-GET instance actions: instance.$action([parameters], [success], [error])

So I was running under the second circumstance where there is no postData parameter.

Changing my code to not instantiate the object, as follows, worked:

```
    //the login function
    authService.login = function(user, success, error) {
        api.Auth.login(null, user).then(
            function(response) {
                var loginData = response;
                authService.getSession();

                $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginSuccess);
                success(loginData);
            }, function(response) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginFailed);
                error(response);
            });
    };
```

For more info see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25930910/565804) (up-voted)